# GPG decryptor doesn't work properly

Tags: java, encryption, bouncycastle, gnupg

I'm trying to write gpg encryptor/decryptor (code below). In first step program encrypts "#data1\n#data2\n#data3\n" string and in next step decrypts the array of bytes that decryptor returns. But... why text from decryptor is not the same as "#data1\n#data2\n#data3\n" ? Where did I missed something ? Thanks for your help.

```
package tests.crypto;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.security.InvalidKeyException;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.security.NoSuchProviderException;
import java.security.PrivateKey;
import java.security.PublicKey;
import java.security.Security;
import java.util.Iterator;

import javax.crypto.BadPaddingException;
import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.IllegalBlockSizeException;
import javax.crypto.NoSuchPaddingException;

import org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider;
import org.bouncycastle.openpgp.PGPException;
import org.bouncycastle.openpgp.PGPPrivateKey;
import org.bouncycastle.openpgp.PGPPublicKey;
import org.bouncycastle.openpgp.PGPPublicKeyRing;
import org.bouncycastle.openpgp.PGPPublicKeyRingCollection;
import org.bouncycastle.openpgp.PGPSecretKey;
import org.bouncycastle.openpgp.PGPSecretKeyRing;
import org.bouncycastle.openpgp.PGPSecretKeyRingCollection;
import org.bouncycastle.openpgp.PGPUtil;
import org.bouncycastle.openpgp.operator.bc.BcPBESecretKeyDecryptorBuilder;
import org.bouncycastle.openpgp.operator.bc.BcPGPDigestCalculatorProvider;
import org.bouncycastle.openpgp.operator.jcajce.JcaPGPKeyConverter;

import Decoder.BASE64Encoder;

public class GPGTest {

    char[] pass = { 'p', 'a', 's', 's' };

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        GPGTest gTest = new GPGTest();
        gTest.setUpCipher();
    }

    public void setUpCipher() throws NoSuchAlgorithmException,
            InvalidKeyException, IllegalBlockSizeException,
            NoSuchProviderException, BadPaddingException,
            NoSuchPaddingException {

        System.out.println("--- setup cipher ---");

        // public key
        String publicKeyFilePath = "E:/Programs/Keys/GPG/Public/public.key";
        File publicKeyFile = new File(publicKeyFilePath);

        // secret key
        String secretKeyFilePath = "E:/Programs/Keys/GPG/Secret/private.key";
        File secretKeyFile = new File(secretKeyFilePath);

        // security provider
        Security.addProvider(new BouncyCastleProvider());

        try {

            // Read the public key
            FileInputStream pubIn = new FileInputStream(publicKeyFile);
            PGPPublicKey pgpPubKey = readPublicKey(pubIn);
            PublicKey pubKey = new JcaPGPKeyConverter().getPublicKey(pgpPubKey);

            // Read the private key
            FileInputStream secretIn = new FileInputStream(secretKeyFile);
            PGPSecretKey pgpSecretKey = readSecretKey(secretIn);
            PGPPrivateKey pgpPrivKey = pgpSecretKey
                    .extractPrivateKey(new BcPBESecretKeyDecryptorBuilder(
                            new BcPGPDigestCalculatorProvider()).build(pass));
            PrivateKey privKey = new JcaPGPKeyConverter()
                    .getPrivateKey(pgpPrivKey);

            Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA");

            // Encrypt data
            byte[] encData = encryptData(cipher, pubKey, new String(
                    "#data1\n#data2\n#data3\n").getBytes());
            String cryptString = new BASE64Encoder().encode(encData);

            System.out.println("\n\nEncrypted data=" + cryptString);

            // Decrypt data
            byte[] decData = decryptData(cipher, privKey, encData);
            String decryptString = new BASE64Encoder().encode(decData);

            System.out.println("\n\nDecrypted data=" + decryptString);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Setup cipher exception");
            System.out.println(e.toString());
        }
    }

    public byte[] encryptData(Cipher cipher, PublicKey pubKey, byte[] clearText) {

        byte[] encryptedBytes = null;
        try {
            cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, pubKey);
            encryptedBytes = cipher.doFinal(clearText);

        } catch (InvalidKeyException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalBlockSizeException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (BadPaddingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return encryptedBytes;
    }

    public byte[] decryptData(Cipher cipher, PrivateKey privKey, byte[] encryptedText) {

        byte[] decryptedBytes = null;
        try {
            cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, privKey);
            decryptedBytes = cipher.doFinal(encryptedText);

        } catch (InvalidKeyException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalBlockSizeException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (BadPaddingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return decryptedBytes;
    }

    private static PGPPublicKey readPublicKey(InputStream input) throws IOException, PGPException {

        PGPPublicKeyRingCollection pgpPub = new PGPPublicKeyRingCollection(PGPUtil.getDecoderStream(input));

        Iterator<?> keyRingIter = pgpPub.getKeyRings();
        while (keyRingIter.hasNext()) {
            PGPPublicKeyRing keyRing = (PGPPublicKeyRing) keyRingIter.next();

            Iterator<?> keyIter = keyRing.getPublicKeys();
            while (keyIter.hasNext()) {
                PGPPublicKey key = (PGPPublicKey) keyIter.next();

                if (key.isEncryptionKey()) {
                    return key;
                }
            }
        }

        throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                "Can't find encryption key in key ring.");
    }

    private static PGPSecretKey readSecretKey(InputStream input) throws IOException, PGPException {

        PGPSecretKeyRingCollection pgpSec = new PGPSecretKeyRingCollection(PGPUtil.getDecoderStream(input));

        Iterator<?> keyRingIter = pgpSec.getKeyRings();
        while (keyRingIter.hasNext()) {
            PGPSecretKeyRing keyRing = (PGPSecretKeyRing) keyRingIter.next();

            Iterator<?> keyIter = keyRing.getSecretKeys();
            while (keyIter.hasNext()) {
                PGPSecretKey key = (PGPSecretKey) keyIter.next();

                if (key.isSigningKey()) {
                    return key;
                }
            }
        }

        throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                "Can't find signing key in key ring.");
    }

}
```

Comment: It would be helpful to know what additional libraries are needed to get the code example to compile. Are you using maven? If so, can you edit the question to include your dependencies?

Answer (score 0):

They aren't the same because you are base-64 encoding the results of the decryption, rather than decoding it as text. Do this instead:

```
byte[] decData = decryptData(cipher, privKey, encData);
System.out.println("\n\nDecrypted data=" + new String(decData));
```

It is poor practice to use the platform default character encoding. Instead, you should convert text to bytes with with specific encoding, and use the same coding when decoding the bytes.

```
byte[] plaintext = "#data1\n#data2\n#data3\n").getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
...
String recovered = new String(decData, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
```